# Using linkedlist to store txt's sentences

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Sorry for my poor code, but I can't understand why this code causes `segmentation fault 11` when I run this on my mac terminal. I want to make the program read full sentences intact one by one using linked list, but it doesn't work.
I guess sentences in `some.txt` aren't getting inserted in `linkNode`. How can I fix it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_NUMBER 1024 

typedef struct linkNode {
    char *element;
    struct linkNode *link;
} linkNode;

typedef struct {
    linkNode *top;
    int element_number;
} linkType;

void error(char* message) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", message);
}

void init(linkType *L) {
    L->top = NULL;
    L->element_number = 0;
}

linkNode *createStack() {
    linkNode *temp = (linkNode *) malloc(sizeof(linkNode));
    temp->element = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_NUMBER + 1);
    return temp;
}

void insert(linkType *L, char* new_data) {
    linkNode *temp = createStack();
    //temp->element = new_data;
    strcpy(temp->element, new_data);
    temp->link = L->top;
    L->element_number++;
    L->top = temp->link;    
}

char *delete(linkType *L) {
    if (L->element_number == 0) {
        error("list empty\n");
    }
    linkNode *temp = L->top;
    char * temp_element;
    //temp->element = L->top->element;
    strcpy(temp_element, L->top->element);
    L->top = L->top->link;
    L->element_number--;
    free(temp);
    return temp_element;
}

char *buffer_making() {
    char *buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_NUMBER + 1);
    return buffer;
}

char *buffer_erase(char *buffer) {
    free(buffer);
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    linkType *q = (linkType *) malloc(sizeof(linkType));
    init(q);
    FILE *file_pointer; 
    char *file1;
    file1 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(file1) + 1); 
    char *file2;
    file2 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(file2) + 1);
    printf("input file names:\n");
    scanf("%s", file1);
    getchar();
    file_pointer = fopen(file1, "r");
    while (!feof(file_pointer)) {
        char *buffer1 = buffer_making();
        fscanf(file_pointer,"%s",buffer1);
        ///////////
        printf("%s\n",buffer1);
        insert(q,buffer1);
        buffer_erase(buffer1);
    }

    printf("point3\n");
    while (!(q->element_number == 0)) {
        printf("%s\n", delete(q));
    }
    free(file1);
    free(file2);

    return 0;
}

//printf("point1\n");
```

Comment: step through it with your debugger

Comment: You will want to look at [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). Also, unless this is a linked list exercise, you are better off using a *pointer-to-pointer-to-char* (e.g. `char**`) and allocating pointers and storage, rather than reading sentences into a linked list. You can do it -- that's fine, it's just an over-complication.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few different issues with your code. Let's go through them one-by-one:

It would be easier to add new elements to the linked list if you keep track of the last node of the list. So you should add another `linkNode` pointer called `bottom` to your `linkType` struct like so:

```
typedef struct {
    linkNode *top;
    linkNode *bottom;
    int element_number;
} linkType;
```

And initialize `bottom` in the `init` function:

```
void init(linkType *L) {
    L->top = NULL;
    L->bottom = NULL;
    L->element_number = 0;
}
```

In the `insert` function, `temp` is the new node that you want to append to the end of the list (if I understand your question correctly), so you need to point its `link` to `NULL` instead of `top`. Also, you should not point `top` to `temp->link`. If this is the first node you are inserting, `top` and `bottom` should both point to `temp`, otherwise `top` will keep pointing to the first node and `bottom` will need to be updated so that it points to `temp`:

```
void insert(linkType *L, char *new_data) {
    linkNode *temp = createStack();
    strcpy(temp->element, new_data);
    temp->link = NULL;
    L->element_number++;

    if (L->top == NULL) {
        L->top = temp;
        L->bottom = temp;
    } else {
        L->bottom->link = temp;
        L->bottom = temp;
    }
}
```

In `delete` function, you don't need to copy the whole string from `element` to `temp_element`; you can just point `temp_element` to `element`. Also, you aren't decrementing `element_number` correctly. The `delete` function should look like:

```
char *delete(linkType *L) {
    if (L->element_number == 0) {
        error("list empty\n");
    }
    linkNode *temp = L->top;
    char *temp_element;
    temp->element = L->top->element;
    L->top = L->top->link;
    (L->element_number)--;
    free(temp);
    return temp_element;
}
```

In the `main` function, you were not reading the input file correctly. `fscanf` scans for words, but since you want to extract sentences instead of words, `fgetc` would be a better approach. The `while` loop for reading should look like:

```
int isEof = 0;
int isEndOfSentence = 0;
int index = 0;

while (!isEof) {
    char *buffer1 = buffer_making();
    isEndOfSentence = 0;
    index = 0;

    while (!isEndOfSentence) {
        char c = fgetc(file_pointer);
        if (c == EOF) {
            isEndOfSentence = 1;
            isEof = 1;
        } else if (c == '.') {
            isEndOfSentence = 1;
        }

        // Skip leading whitespace
        if ((isEof || c == ' ' || c == '\n') && index == 0) {
          continue;
        }

        buffer1[index++] = c;
    }

    // Skip empty sentence
    if (index == 0) {
        continue;
    }

    buffer1[index] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", buffer1);
    insert(q, buffer1);
    buffer_erase(buffer1);
}
```

This is not the best way to implement reading sentences, but it works. Also, this code assumes that sentences end in `.`. You can update this code to make it work for sentences that end in `?`, `!`, etc.

Finally, the `while` loop where you delete as well as print each node's `element` seems to have some issues. You can instead use the following `while` loop:

```
while (!(q->element_number == 0)) {
    printf("%s\n", q->top->element);
    delete(q);
}
```

Hope this helps. I've tested these changes and they work for me.

Answer (score 0):

From `valgrind`:

```
==18918== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==18918==    at 0x4C2E119: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:458)
==18918==    by 0x4EA4E81: puts (in /lib64/libc-2.25.so)
==18918==    by 0x108BE8: main (ll.c:74)
==18918== 

==18918== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==18918==    at 0x4C2E1FB: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:510)
==18918==    by 0x108A49: insert (ll.c:31)
==18918==    by 0x108BFB: main (ll.c:75)
==18918== 

==18918== Invalid read of size 8
==18918==    at 0x108AB1: delete (ll.c:44)
==18918==    by 0x108C31: main (ll.c:82)
==18918==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

gcc also reports an issue with `-Wall`:

```
ll.c: In function ‘delete’:
ll.c:44:5: warning: ‘temp_element’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     strcpy(temp_element,L->top->element);
```

One problem is that you're calling `strcpy` without allocating memory for the destination.  Another problem is that you're dereferencing `L->top` without verifying it's non-`NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

with my friends' helps, I could make it print right outcomes in my terminals!  special thanks to those who answered my questions! thank you!

Actually what I really wanted was just linked list which indicated by only linkNode *top, I edited what i intended. :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_NUMBER 1024 
typedef struct linkNode{
    char * element;
    struct linkNode * link;
}linkNode;
typedef struct{
    linkNode *top;
    int element_number;
}linkType;

void error(char* message){
    fprintf(stderr,"%s", message);
}
void init(linkType *L){

    L->top=NULL;
    L->element_number = 0;
}
linkNode * createStack(){
    linkNode * temp = (linkNode *)malloc(sizeof(linkNode));
    temp->element = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_NUMBER+1);
    return temp;
}

void insert(linkType *L,char* new_data){
    linkNode *temp = createStack();
    //temp->element = new_data;
    strcpy(temp->element,new_data);
    temp -> link = NULL;
    L->element_number++;
    if(L->top ==NULL){
        L->top =temp;
    }
    else{
    temp->link = L->top;
    L->top = temp;  
    }
}
char * delete(linkType *L){
    if(L->element_number ==0)
    {
        error("list empty\n");
    }
    linkNode *temp = NULL;
    temp = L->top;
    char * temp_element;
    temp->element = L->top->element;
    L->top = L->top->link;
    (L->element_number)--;
    free(temp);
    return temp_element;
}
char * buffer_making(){
    char* buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_NUMBER+1);
    return buffer;
}
char * buffer_erase(char * buffer){
    free(buffer);
    return NULL;
}
int main(){
    linkType q ;
    init(&q);
    FILE *file_pointer; 
    char * file1;
    file1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(file1)+1); 
    char * file2;
    file2 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(file2)+1);
    printf("input file names:\n");
    scanf("%s",file1);
    getchar();
    file_pointer=fopen(file1,"r");

    while(1){
    char * buffer1 = buffer_making();
    if(fscanf(file_pointer,"%s",buffer1)==EOF) break;
    ///////////
    printf("%s\n",buffer1);
    insert(&q,buffer1);
    buffer_erase(buffer1);
    }

    printf("point3\n");
    while(!(q.element_number==0))
    {
        printf("%s\n", q.top->element);
        delete(&q);
    }
    free(file1);
    free(file2);
    return 0;
}
```